# Incorrect Answer Rate being displayed

Tags: bug, status-completed

This is from the [Skeptics.SE front page](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com), but it is affecting all sites.

[image]

The real answer rate is around 88%; it has recently started being reported incorrectly.

**Stop Press**: The first fix to the issue has changed it to -88%:

[image: Updated image]

Thanks to Sklivvz for the image; sorry we didn't have time to hand-draw the circle.

Comment: No, it just doesn't trust that your questions got actual or worthy answers.

Comment: I'm skeptical of your claims.

Comment: `num_jokes_about_disbelieving_a_skeptic += 2;`

Comment: +1: Same on [Travel-SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It is also broken over here at Travel SE. We're down to 5% instead of our normal 99% or 100%

Comment: @Roflcoptr: We're down to 5% on [LEGO Answers](http://bricks.stackexchange.com) as well.

Comment: Same for [Linguistics.se]. But if you check the Area 51 it's all right. The problem is just on the main site.

Comment: You think you've done badly. We've got -114% on http://econonomics.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kjzLi.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was an API glitch here showing the inverse number of what was intended.  It just now showed up because we just finished moving everything internally off APIv1 and onto APIv2.

The bug is fixed, but the ad is cached for an hour...so it will take a bit for the fix to show up.

**Update:** now it's *actually* fixed, and the stats are updated.  The percentages may still be off vs the unanswered tab as the API doesn't exclude closed questions, checking with Monty to see if that's intentional or not, we'll update it if needed.

Comment: Are there any other components which uses API?

Comment: @Martin - Yes, we are the biggest consumer of our API - we dogfood heavily.

Comment: why do you do so? Is it easier for you to call API instead of calling function?

Comment: Uh, I suspect the fix isn't working. We are now at -88%. We'll never graduate at this rate :-)

Comment: Yes it is even more wrong now... -185% here on Travel SE

Comment: -156% on Linguistics. :D

Comment: Movies isn't as bad, showing -86%

Comment: The "glitch" now has worsened. No [really](http://i.imgur.com/kjzLi.png).

Comment: It means you have too many questions in your answers, perhaps editing can fix that?`</sarcasm>`

Comment: @Alenanno [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) is at -263%.

Comment: @Oddthinking - you guys should really answer more questions, that's a horrible answer rate.

Comment: @Nick: First, thanks for the fix! Are you suggesting our new figure of (gulp) 82% is "horrible"? Area 51 is putting us at "90% Excellent"; the discrepancy is likely because of the high proportion of questions in the closed state. Second, it's a topic that [has been researched before](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1225). Skeptics.SE have a culture of high-quality, high-effort answers; this figure belies the fact that 90% of opened questions have pretty damned good answers!

Comment: @Oddthinking I think you missed the sarcasm.  I read that as a response to your "*We are now at -88%*" comment =)

Comment: @jadarnel27: Darn it. My first draft of the comment didn't fit in the character limit, but it apologised if I was missing the sarcasm. The timeline seems to suggest he made the comment afterwards, but "Well, to tell you the truth, in all this excitement I kind of lost track myself." Maybe I am a bit sensitive about the topic.